# How to read input again in a for loop?

Tags: python

I'm a freshman of Python, and now meet a problem I can't understand. How to recall an input outside of a for loop?

Please some master give me an answer using the following example. Tks!

---

```
n=int(input('Please input a number: ')

for i in range(2,n):

    if n%i==0:
        print('It is not a prime number!',  end=' ')
        break
    else:
        print('%d is a prime number!' % n)
```

Comment: You question isn't clear. What do you want to know outside the for loop?

Comment: There is an indentation problem after the for. Be careful !

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking. What have you tried?

Comment: Use a loop enclosing the whole code to read input number again. :P

Comment: If the number is't a prime number, how can i return the input again?

Comment: @Austin Could you please give me an example? Tks

Comment: Do you want to continue inputting till you get a response, then just write a infinite loop outside your code, which will keep asking you for input till you input a prime number, and then the code will break, see my example below

Comment: One thing no-one has mentioned is that you shouldn't loop over `range(2,n)` as you don't need to check any values higher than sqrt(n) as they can't possibly be factors of n. `range(2,int(n**0.5)+1)` would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just put another loop around your code. e.g.

```
while True:
    n=int(input('Please input a number: '))

    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i==0:
            print('It is not a prime number!',  end=' ')
        else:
            print('%d is a prime number!' % n)
            break
```

Comment: I did not understand your comment @Hawker ! Could you please explain me again! Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
while True:
    n=int(input('Please input a number: ')
    flag = True
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i==0:
            flag = False
            break

    if flag == True:
        print('%d is a prime number!' % n)
        break
    else:
        print('It is not a prime number!',  end=' ')
```